# Overloading function to handle multiple value classes in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a C++11 hashmap class (mostly for fun), and I'd like my insert function to be able to handle any value class efficiently (ie it uses move semantics when possible).

So what I did is write 4 overloads of my insert:

```
template <class K, class V>
struct hashmap {
    <snip>
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (K&& key, V&& val);                  
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (K   key, V&& val);      
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (K&& key, V  val);      
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (K   key, V  val);      
    <snip>
};
```

And defined them so the one with two rvalue references is the "real" insert, and the others use std::forward/std::move as appropriate to pass their arguments to it.

```
// insert operator.  If the key doesn't exist in the table, build it with
// the given value.  If it does exist, overwrite it with new value.  Other
// insert variants wrap this with appropriate forward/move semantics
template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(K&& key, V&& val) {
    using std::swap; // for ADL
    using std::move;
    using std::forward;

    if (capacity_ == 0) {
        resize_(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    }

    size_t hash = hash_key(key);
    size_t idx  = modulo(hash, capacity_);

    // scan through container until we find an empty bucket.  If we find the key
    // along the way, just set its value and we're done.  If we find any elements
    // with a smaller probe distance than ours, swap with them and continue loop
    bool swapped=false;
    for (size_t ii=0, curdist=0;  ii < capacity_;  ii++, curdist++) {
        size_t pos = modulo(idx + ii, capacity_);

        if (storage_[pos].hash == EMPTY_BUCKET) {
            // found an empty bucket, place what we currently have there
            if (used_ >= 3*capacity_/4) {
                // if loading is > 75% then resize the table and call back to insert to place element
                resize_(2*capacity_);
                insert(forward<K>(key), forward<V>(val));
            } else {
                // otherwise just build the new hash bucket as requested
                storage_[pos].hash = hash;
                new (&storage_[pos].kv.key) K(forward<K>(key));
                new (&storage_[pos].kv.val) V(forward<V>(val));
                used_++;
            }
            break;

        } else if (!swapped && storage_[pos].hash == hash && (storage_[pos].kv.key == key)) {
            // found a bucket that matches our key, update it
            storage_[pos].kv.val = forward<V>(val);
            break;

        } else {
            // found non-empty bucket that doesn't match us. If it has a probe distance
            // less than ours, we'll swap with it and continue looking to place the element
            size_t newdist = probedist(storage_[pos].hash, pos);
            if (newdist < curdist) {
                curdist = newdist;
                swap(storage_[pos].hash,   hash);
                swap(storage_[pos].kv.key, key);
                swap(storage_[pos].kv.val, val);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}


// insert variants for different value classes
template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(K   key, V&& val) { insert(std::move(key),    std::forward(val)); return *this; }

template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(K&& key, V   val) { insert(std::forward(key), std::move(val));    return *this; }

template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(K   key, V   val) { insert(std::move(key),    std::move(val));    return *this; }
```

Naturally, after I made this change, I tried to insert a std::string, size_t pair into an instance:

```
maph.insert(*ptr++, ii);
```

And immediately got a compiler error complaining about ambiguous calls:

```
src/check_hash.cc:313:5:   required from here
src/check_hash.cc:128:13: error: call of overloaded ‘insert(std::basic_string<char>&, size_t&)’ is ambiguous
             maph.insert(*ptr++, ii);
             ^
src/check_hash.cc:128:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from src/check_hash.cc:9:
hashmap.h:243:23: note: prelude::{anonymous}::hashmap<K, V>& prelude::{anonymous}::hashmap<K, V>::insert(K, V&&) [with K = std::basic_string<char>; V = int]
         hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(K   key, V&& val) { insert(std::move(key),    std::forward(val)); return *this; }
                       ^
prelude/hashmap.h:39:27: note: prelude::{anonymous}::hashmap<K, V>& prelude::{anonymous}::hashmap<K, V>::insert(K, V) [with K = std::basic_string<char>; V = int]
             hashmap<K,V>& insert (K   key, V  val);
```

---

What would be the right way to do this to be able to accomodate all 4 combinations of key/value types?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according to the C++11 spec, if you define a function with an rvalue reference:

```
void example(Type&& t);
```

But neither of:

```
void example(Type& t)
```

or

```
void example(const Type& t)
```

Then the function is *only* callable with rvalues, which makes some amount of sense, since taking parameters by value, the temporary can be constructed either from rvalue or lvalue so it's ambiguous.  The solution is to take const lvalue references:

```
template <class K, class V>
struct hashmap {
    <snip>
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (      K&& key,       V&& val);                  
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (const K&  key,       V&& val);      
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (      K&& key, const V&  val);      
    hashmap<K,V>& insert (const K&  key, const V&  val);      
    <snip>
};
```

And then make the copies manually:

```
// insert variants for different value classes
template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(const K&  key,       V&& val) { insert(std::move(K(key)),    std::forward<V>(val)); return *this; }

template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(      K&& key, const V&  val) { insert(std::forward<K>(key), std::move(V(val)));    return *this; }

template <class K, class V>
hashmap<K,V>& hashmap<K,V>::insert(const K&  key, const V&  val) { insert(std::move(K(key)),    std::move(V(val)));    return *this; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you plan on making a copy/move of `val` anyway, accept that argument by value. For the key, use the perfect forwarding idiom. However, you need to have the compiler deduce the rvalue/lvalue-ness since it might be different from the class template argument `K` by introducing a template parameter for `insert`. Here is one signature which captures it all:

```
template <typename Key, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<K, std::decay_t<Key>>>>
hashmap& insert(Key&&, V);
```

Note that `hashmap` in the definition of the class means `hashmap<K,V>`. You don't need to specify it explicitly.